# Typo3 12 RTE_CKEditor Image integration

Tags: image, typo3, rte

i wnat to insert inline Text images in Typo3 12 RTE Editor, but i found no way to integrate it.
I try to add it to the toolbar, but without any success.
Does anyone has an idea?

This is my try:

```
editor:
  config:
    toolbar:
      items:
        - image
```

Answer (score 0):

TYPO3 explicitly disables it in rte_ckeditor. There is an extension [rte_ckeditor_image](https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/rte_ckeditor_image). You can use that or look in the extension how it is solved.

If you make it possible to insert images, you should also make sure the soft references are added to the reference index (sys_refindex). The extension rte_ckeditor_image also takes care of that (with an own soft reference parser).

However I would strongly think about whether you want to go down that road (in fact I would not recommend it):

- you are adding a non-standard mechanism which TYPO3 does not support and has to be maintained long-term
- image handling can be quite complicated if you also want to support supplying different image sizes and cropping depending on the viewport size (responsive images).
- once you allow the `<img>` tag, it is also possible to copy-paste images in the RTE. While this can be very convenient for the editors, you will have inline images in the RTE field in the database with all the consequences: It bloats up the database and it is not possible to automatically convert it to a file later because you don't have any metadata for it. (What should the file be called? Where should it be located?)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. The extension rte_ckeditor_image seems not to be working for Typo3 12, but I need the image Button only for a normal Image without any responsive functions. Is there another way to enable the Button?

Comment: The source code of the extension is online. https://github.com/netresearch/t3x-rte_ckeditor_image. Either create a PR to make it work for v12, or use the functionality you need, you can start with enabling the button: https://github.com/netresearch/t3x-rte_ckeditor_image/blob/master/Configuration/RTE/Plugin.yaml